# Can I use together: Zipkin, Sleuth, MDC, ELK, Jaeger?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, jaeger, mdc

I really read many articles. I figure out that need to just include a starters in spring boot )))

Can anyone sort it out: is Sleuth create MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context)? Is sleuth create a record's ID which used by Zipkin? Can I see this ID in Kibana? Or do I need to use zipkin API? Are there best practice to use all of this together? Is Jaeger substitute both Zipkin and Sleuth or how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, and I have shown that numerous times during my presentations (https://toomuchcoding.com/talks) and we describe it extensively in the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/). Sleuth will set up your logging pattern which you can then parse and visualize using the ELK stack. Sleuth takes care of tracing context propagation and can send the spans to a span storage (e.g. Zipkin or Jaeger). Sleuth does take care of updating the MDC for you. Please always read the documentation and the project page before filing a question